# What exactly does the data structure of the inverted index in SOLR looks like

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, inverted-index

All, Forgive me I am just beginning to learn how to work with `SOLR`. The powerful SE. 
And I already knew that `Inverted Index` is the reason why the search is so fast in the `SOLR`. In many read . Like `Solr in action`, `Apache Solr search pattern`. The inverted index is mentioned and described like below.

[image]

And I also knew the `Document` is made of `Fields`.
In my understanding of the above data structure. When searching with a specific term like "Harry". The SE will return the result document 1,2. I have no question with it.

But when I read the [guide from apache](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analyzers). It says

> Analysis takes place in two contexts. At index time, when a field is
>   being created, the token stream that results from analysis is added to
>   an index and defines the set of terms (including positions, sizes, and
>   so on) for the field. At query time, the values being searched for are
>   analyzed and the terms that result are matched against those that are
>   stored in the field's index.

I am confused with this read .

Does the inverted index is pointing to the document or field ?
In the diagram I mentioned. It doesn't mention anything about field. It just said index is pointing to the document id. 
But in the read I quoted. It does tell us the inverted index is pointing to the field not to the document. (If I was wrong . Please correct me.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your confusion, this is one of those cases where the literature explains an over simplification of the subject in hand. Most of the literature explains and Inverted Index using documents that are just text, so (as shown in the figure) one document is only a sequence of characters, and no other "fields" exist.

This becomes useful when you're explaining what an Inverted Index is, but when you interact with an actual implementation (like the one provided by Lucene/ES/Solr) the reality is a bit different.

Perhaps [this post](http://hackerlabs.org/blog/2011/10/01/hacking-lucene-the-index-format/) could be of use, the reading is a bit dense if you go all the way down, but if you just try to grasp the essentials and don't try to understand everything in one read. Be advice, the Lucene implementation contains a lot more of technical details, to ensure performance and reduced disk usage, for instance.

Bottom line is that basically each field is like a "mini inverted index" on its own, and allow to know in which particular "part/field" of your document the match with your query happened, so you can influence your score (usually how results are ordered) accordingly. If you always had flat documents, the search engine wouldn't be so useful.

Comment: Thanks your understanding . +1 For the first sentence.

Comment: Could you please check the link ? It is broken. return 404.. Thanks.http://hackerlabs.org/blog/2011/10/01/hacking-lucene-the-index-format/

Comment: WOW! sorry about that, the site was fine when I posted the reply, try to use the cached google version, worked for me.

Comment: LOL , Wonderful!  All the things are what I was looking for . Thanks your awesome piece.

Answer (score 0):

i may be understand your confusion, if you want to comprehensize understand solr searching , indexing , analysis, i think you must be study lucene first . 
 why ?   because solr is base on lucene , this is a lucene wiki url , helpful it can help you !  [lucene wiki](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the example you mentioned above.  We have 2 docs:

```
Doc1: Harry Potter And The Half Blood Prince

Doc2: Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows
```

**To build inverted index**

- **Step 1** - we need tokenize those docs into terms with a tokenizer. 
  So, let's say, we use Tokenizer A and get following results:

  Doc1: `Harry`, `Potter`, `And`, `The`, `Half`, `Blood`, `Prince`

  Doc2: `Harry`, `Potter`, `And`, `The`, `Deathly`, `Hallows`
- **Step 2** - Build inverted index

  `Harry`   ->  Doc1, Doc2

  `Potter`  ->  Doc1, Doc2

  `And`     ->  Doc1, Doc2

  `The`     ->  Doc1, Doc2

  `Half`    ->  Doc1

  `Blood`   ->  Doc1

  `Prince`  ->  Doc1

  `Deathly` ->  Doc2

  `Hallows` ->  Doc2

**To query/search**

- **Step 1** - We also need tokenize search words at first

  Such as, our search words are `Harry Potter`. And you have two
  tokenizer to choose. Tokenizer A is same with the one we use during
  indexing, will tokenize our words into two terms: `Harry` and
  `Potter`. But Tokenzier B can tokenzie them into just on term `Harry
  Potter`.
- **Step 2** - Do query

  If you choose Tokenizer A, you get `Harry` and `Potter`, both of them are in our inverted index, then you can get search results: Doc1 and Doc2.
  But if you choose Tokenizer B, you get term `Harry Potter` which is not in our inverted index, that means you can't retrieve any results from inverted index.

> **Conclusion**:  Everything in Solr/Lucene both indexing and searching are
>   based on terms.  You can choose different tokenizers/filters or
>   combine them together during indexing or searching, and you will get
>   different terms output.  Please refer this
>   [http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/](http://Conclusion:%20%20Everything%20in%20Solr/Lucene%20both%20indexing%20and%20searching%20are%20based%20on%20terms.%20%20You%20can%20choose%20different%20tokenizers/filters%20or%20combine%20them%20together%20during%20indexing%20or%20searching,%20and%20you%20will%20get%20different%20terms%20output.%20%20Please%20refer%20this%20http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters/.%20%20This%20can%20help%20you%20to%20design%20your%20solr%20depends%20on%20your%20specific%20requirements.). 
>   It can help you to design your solr depends on your specific
>   requirements.

Comment: Yes , It is the most popular example from the tutorial like `Solr in action` , `AppacheSolrSearchPattern` trying to explain the issue about How search works , and How index structure looks like . But I think it is just the some theoretical example . It is not the one reflecting the real world. I believe it should be more complicated than the example you showed to me. Thanks.

Comment: My question is when doing search. What is the use of field ? The example you show me didn't mentioned anything about the field ..

Answer (score 0):

In first approximation an inverted index is just ordered (from law to height) arrays of documents ids. It allows made fast intersections and unions of documents ids when you search for several terms. To provide faster intersection, even than linear timing , it contains a [skip pointers](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/faster-postings-list-intersection-via-skip-pointers-1.html), you can read about it in a book [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/). This book is a great introduction into how general search engine works. To reduce i/o for disc operations and index size some compression mechanisms is used, you can read an [introduction to them](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/index-compression-1.html) also in this book.